# Android slide animation problem

Tags: android, animation

I have a 3 horizontal views - an image on the left which is a thin vertical handle-type bar and an image to its right followed by a textview. What I'm trying to achieve is a sliding animation, activated with a click on the handle, so that the center image slides in and out to the left (and so disappearing when fully left) with the textview following this animation smoothly. The effect will be the handle remains in place (hence I can't use the SlidingDrawer), the image comes and goes and the textview is always present but slides into the space where the image went. Its just collapsing the image really.

The problem is if I apply android.R.anim.slide_in_left/android.R.anim.slide_out_left to the image and the textview simultaneously I see they slide completely to the left edge of the screen, temporarily overwriting the handle. Is there a way to still animate but not go all the way to the screen edge?